# is it possible to have more than one text style in a text holder?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I want to set up a text holder that shows that your header should be bold, and the body copy should be light (for example). When I set up a text holder it initially appears with placeholder text in 'levels' which suggests it is possible, but when I edit these levels this does not appear in the actual slide, it just shows one text style (whichever is at the top of the text holder). Where am I going wrong? Or is this just not possible?
thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What do you mean by text holder? A text box? A shape?

Comment: Hello! Its a text box, but its specifically a holder (as I understand it) because its the text box you make in the master slide that then appears in the front end as an editable text box.

Comment: It is possible if you have multiple levels that you can trigger by indents.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my CustomLayout. I have edited the text-holder by selecting the particular lines and changing its formatting to look something like this:

[image]

In my normal slides, I can type within the placeholder. To trigger the formatting of Level 2 and the others, I'll have to indent the line by pressing `TAB` on my keyboard. My final result looks something like this:

[image]